# Issuing "apt-get update" command on ubuntu AWS EC2 instance upgrades PHP version from 7.1 to 7.2?

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

Please let me know if issuing "apt-get update" command on AWS EC2 ubuntu 14.04   machine upgrades PHP version from 7.1 to 7.2

Answer (score 1):

Well, apt-get update updates the apt-get list of repositories, to update the packages installed by apt-get you should use apt-get upgrade:

```
# apt-get upgrade php7
```

or

```
# apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Hi desoares, Thanks for your reply. I had installed PHP through apt-get and now I don't want my PHP version to be upgraded from 7.1 to a greater version but still when I check after issuing the apt-get command I have noticed that PHP version got upgraded. I think that by issuing apt-get only OS variables get updated but not the software's installed.I just want to confirm if I am thinking wrong.

Comment: apt-get update is usually used to prepare the environment for the installation of some package, when you add an repository the the apt-get list and before installing the new package. You you are having issues you should install the PHP package after the last need to update. The best place to ask this is Ask ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot desoares. I will check in askubunntu.com .

Answer (score 1):

You can confirm that with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade --dry-run
```

Based on [Linux Man Page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get):

> No action. Perform a simulation of events that would occur but do not
>   actually change the system.